# Why does cvt change my res value?

Tags: display, resolution, xrandr

I have problems with my resolution and I wanted to adjust it with the help of xrandr, but when I try to set it up it changes the values..

```
fabio@fabio-EasyNote-TS11HR ~ $ cvt 1366 768
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

so it changes my 1366 in 1368 and when i try xrandr:

```
fabio@fabio-EasyNote-TS11HR ~ $ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
Serial number of failed request:  19
Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here ... I'm using dell xps14z

I got it **partially** working with 1360x768 and to make the changes permanent I added this lines to .profile hidden file like this:

```
gksu gedit ~/.profile
```

then at the end of the file I added:

```
xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00"   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1360x768_60.00
```

> when I reboot I still get 640x480 in the login screen but after successful login I get 1360x768

Just to mention it: I got into this problem after trying to enable Unity 3D which I got using [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Comment: To run a graphical application like `gedit` as `root`, you should use `gksu`/`gksudo` instead of `sudo`, as running `gedit` directly with `sudo` can [prevent it from working correctly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) when run as the limited (non-`root`) user.